# Django docker error table not exist

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I had a existing Django Rest project with an existing MySQL database (named libraries) which I wanted to Dockerize.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: libraries
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes: 
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

**Steps:**

1. I ran: `docker-compose build` - build was successful
2. I ran: `docker-compose up` - had to run this command twice and then I could access my API by hitting localhost:8000

However, whenever I hit any API endpoint I get an error Table "XYZ" does not exist. All the tables are already present.

Why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's strange that you had to run `docker-compose up` twice. I recommend to run `docker logs` after the first run to see what goes wrong, then start another question if you need help.

Regarding your main question, keep it mind that docker containers are stateless. That means unless you add persistent volume configurations, you'll get the same "fresh" one every time you start a new container.

Based on your compose file, there are two containers: a "web" one and a "db" one. A fresh "db" one just contains an empty MySQL instance with db name, db user, and db password settings. There's no data in it. You have two options:

1. Run `migration` from your "web" container to set up the db schema in your "db" container.
2. If you have some data in your local/dev setting and want to use them, consider backing up these data from your local setting then restoring it into your "db" container. In case you don't know how, consult MySQL documents to see how to backup data, and consult the "Initializing a fresh instance" part of the [MySQL docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) to see how to start a new "db" container with some data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Running migrations from web container solved the problem. As I am totally new to docker (I am still learning), I am trying out things step by step. Understanding things conceptually is so necessary here.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to run django migrations:

```
$ docker exec -it [container] bash
# python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Or in one fell swoop, just run `docker exec -it <container> python manage.py migrate --noinput` and it will run migrations all in one go